# regex $1 Symbol read once bug

Tags: javascript, regex

## regex $1 Symbol read once bug

> why I can only read once `RegExp.$1`?

[image]

[image]

```js
var e = 99;
var t = `MSIE 93`;
var ie = new RegExp("MSIE ([0-9]{1,}[.0-9]{0,})").exec(t);
ie != null && (e = parseFloat(RegExp.$1));
// 93

console.log(ie);
// (2) ["MSIE 93", "93", index: 0, input: "MSIE 93", groups: undefined]
console.log(ie[0]);
// "MSIE 93"
console.log(RegExp.$1);
// " "
```

```js
var e = 99;
var t = `MSIE 93`;
var ie = new RegExp("MSIE ([0-9]{1,}[.0-9]{0,})").exec(t);
ie != null && (e = parseFloat(RegExp.$1));
// 93

console.log(ie);
// (2) ["MSIE 93", "93", index: 0, input: "MSIE 93", groups: undefined]
console.log(RegExp.$1);
// "93"
console.log(RegExp.$1);
// ""
```

### env

[image]

[image]

### ⚠️ no need anymore.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/n

Comment: I can't reproduce on FF nor on Chrome 78.0.3904.108, either in the console or in the snippets. What environment are you running this in?

Comment: which version of browser do you use? in my latest mozilla browser, the result is always `")"`. by the way, it is a deprecated method.

Comment: Chrome Canary Version 80.0.3982.0 (Official Build) canary (64-bit)

Comment: you are right, that's Chrome version bug!

Comment: @xgqfrms Can you link the bug report, please?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it's no longer needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Chrome canary version bug

### testing OK

> Version 78.0.3904.108 (Official Build) (64-bit)

[image]

[image]

Comment: close this question